# How to connect two devices via USB with type b and mini-b male connectors

Tags: usb, label-printer

***Case 1: Male Type B / Male Mini-B***

- I have a printer with a USB female Type B connector.
- I also have a handheld terminal with a USB female Mini-B connector.
- I would like to connect the handheld terminal to the printer.

Can I do that with one USB cable only, and if so, how? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) there is no such cable.

If such a cable doesn't exist, how can I connect the two devices in USB?

***Case 2: Male Mini-B / Male Mini-B***

- I have a printer with a USB female Mini-B connector.
- I also have a handheld terminal with a USB female Mini-B connector.
- I would like to connect the handheld terminal to the printer.

How can I do that with one USB cable only? Wikipedia also claims there is no such cable for this. If such a cable doesn't exist, how can I connect the two devices?

For clarification, I have a Zebra GK420t printer and a Datalogic Memor handheld computer that I would like to connect together via USB, if it is possible of course.

I tried to describe the connectors as I see them.

I would like to know if it's possible to do so and if yes, how.

Comment: Thanks. How can I check that the terminal supports being a HOST on the USB BUS? (Again, I don't know much about USB).

Comment: Note: the two cases are distinct (not the same printers). I actually need two distinct solutions, one for each case.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such a cable for reason. If you connect two *USB hosts* with such a cable, you have high chances to fry either one or both of them.

Basically, if your terminal have *USB OTG* (host), you may connect your printer with conventional A-B cable and mini-B to female-A pass-through (look for "USB A Female to Mini USB B"). Though, as @Journeyman mentioned in comments, you'll also need drivers for your printer.

But if it doesn't have host, it won't work (and usually it doesn't hurt to connect two USB guests altogether).

Best look in manual of your terminal what connection options are available. Sometimes you need very special kind of cable for such an operation.

P.S. Don't hesitate to google any terms you find yourself unfamiliar with.

Comment: To add to that - this is a great answer as is, but its worth noteing The reason the  USB standard (Not counting 3.1 type C) has different connections for host (type A) and device (type B, mini type A and B and micro type A) is that you never want to plug in host to host. USB OTG is special in that its a 5 pin connector with the 5th pin shorted in OTG mode. Also, OP would need drivers for the printer even if it worked.